# Elasticsearch (n) documents per property value

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I have an Elasticsearch instance with about 3.5Million records and I want a fast way to return (n) records per property value in any given search.

### Example

`Document 1:`

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "gender": "male",
    "name": "Joe"
}
```

`Document 2:`

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "gender": "male",
    "name": "John"
}
```

`Document 3:`

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "gender": "female",
    "name": "Jill"
}
```

`Document 4:`

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "gender": "female",
    "name": "Joan"
}
```

#### Assuming a match_all search

I only want to return 1 document for each value of the `gender` property:
For instance, return only doc 1 and doc 3

This would obviously be spread across a much larger result set, but the result should still scale to (n) docs per unique property value.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an aggregation for "gender" field together with a "top_hits" aggregation to return `n` hits per each "gender" value:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{}]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_gender": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_hit": {
          "top_hits": {"size":1}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can that be combined with a boolean filter?

Comment: Yes. Instead of the "match_all" query, you can put something like the updated version I put.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. Unfortunately it's bloody slow... :( Still gave you the win though, since you did answer my question.